# MongoError: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb 3.4.2. I'm getting the error "MongoError: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)". I have nested data.Image of my sample collection. Does anyone have any suggestions on this topic?

```
    this.model.aggregate([
            {
                $unwind : "$unitID"
            },
            {
                $match:{
                    "unitID":{
                        "$in":unitObjList
                    }
                }
            },
        ],cb)
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions about what?
If you want to decrease the document size instead of saving the image inside the DB, store an URL that points to object storage, like S3 where you save the image.
If it's not an option or you still have the issue you should paginate your query, you can take a look to this blog [post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1)

Comment: ```$project: {
                    "costPhotos": 0
                }```  it is not enough when I do it. I don't think it's relevant to the images